# Is there a way to turn off a language in Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, language

I have a site that serves German content. Now we have an admin that wants to have the backend in English.

So I've added English in the locales. This works fine for standard Craft things.

But in Craft Commerce all of the products are now in two languages. Is there a way to turn off the language for Craft Commerce?

I've looked into product types, but you can't just turn off a language.

Problem is, that this admin is also the CEO of that shop.

Comment: You don't have to add another local in order to change the backend language. Every user can chose which language should be displayed in his/her account settings. Thus you can remove the second local and everything should be fine

Comment: I don't think you're right. To be able to choose a language you have to activate it in the locale settings. There's nothing to choose from in the user settings if there's only one language activated. Please double check.

Comment: Oh sry you have a Craft 2 project.. yeah this won't work for Craft 2 you would need to update to Craft 3 in order to set the language you want.

Comment: At least it's been taken care of!

Comment: How are we going to distinguish between craft 2 and 3 in stackexchange? are there any guidelines?

Comment: so there's really no way to deactivate languages in craft commerce?